# Merging trips to the same location with overlapping dates

Tags: c#, datetime, linq, sqlite, interval

I have a SQLite database that only contains the holidays for 1 user.

I have a new `Trip` object (`newTrip`) that has a `StartDate`(`long` unix time) and an `EndDate`(`long` unix time) and the trip `Iso3Code`(`string`) for the location.

I need to retrieve from the database all existing `Trip`s that can be merged with the `newTrip`. A trip can be merged if the dates of the new trip fall at the same time of the existing trips or on the day before or after the existing trips and have the same Iso2Code`.

So far I have this:

```
public static List<Trip> GetTripsThatCanBeMerged(Trip trip)
{
    //ignore times - just get for that date and get the date before for the start date and the day after for the end data, as the day before and after can be merged.
    DateTime startDate = DateTimeHelper.UnixDateToDateTime(trip.StartDate).Date.AddDays(-1);
    DateTime endDate = DateTimeHelper.UnixDateToDateTime(trip.EndDate).Date.AddDays(1);

    //now convert back to unix
    long startDateUnix = DateTimeHelper.DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(startDate);
    long endDateUnix = DateTimeHelper.DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(endDate);

    List<Trip> trips = null;

    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), _sqliteDatabasePath))
    {
        trips = conn.GetAllWithChildren<Trip>(p => 
            ((p.StartDate >= startDateUnix && p.StartDate <= endDateUnix) || 
            (p.EndDate >= startDateUnix && p.EndDate <= endDateUnix) || 
            (p.StartDate <= startDateUnix && (endDateUnix >= p.StartDate && endDateUnix <= p.EndDate))) &&
            p.Iso3Code == trip.Iso3Code
            , true);
    }

    return trips;
}
```

I think this is correct but can anyone suggest a less complex way of doing it, or see any errors.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Nice first question!

Comment: Thanks. hoping someone has a better way of doing it or spots any mistakes!

Comment: So if (newTrip startDate) == (existingTrip endDate +1 day) the trips should be merged even if (newTrip endDate) is several days later?  Or does the newTrip have to fall entirely between existingTrip (endDate +1) and (startDate - 1) ?

Comment: @forsvarir if (newTrip startDate) == (existingTrip endDate +1 day) the trips should be merged - yes to this, so e.g. existing is Mon - Wed and newTrip is Thurs - Fri, these should be merged to 1 trip of Mon-Fri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at this line:

> ```
> (p.StartDate <= startDateUnix && (endDateUnix >= p.StartDate && endDateUnix <= p.EndDate))
> ```

If `p.StartDate <= startDateUnix` then `p.StartDate <= endDateUnix`, since `startDateUnix <= endDateUnix`. So `endDateUnix >= p.StartDate` is redundant.

So the first part of the query can be written as

```
(p.StartDate >= startDateUnix && p.StartDate <= endDateUnix) || 
(p.EndDate >= startDateUnix && p.EndDate <= endDateUnix) || 
(p.StartDate <= startDateUnix && endDateUnix <= p.EndDate)
```

I would recommend rewriting the first two conditions as follows:

```
(startDateUnix <= p.StartDate && p.StartDate <= endDateUnix) || 
(startDateUnix <= p.EndDate && p.EndDate <= endDateUnix)
```

I find it easier to see at a glance that it's saying that `p.StartDate` lies within `[startDateUnix, endDateUnix]` (similarly for `p.EndDate`).

---

[Another way](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestIfDateRangesOverlap) to [test for overlapping intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269471/1220238) is

```
p.StartDate <= endDateUnix && startDateUnix <= p.EndDate
```

Comment: Based on you saying the part of the first line is redundant, I think that some of the 3rd line is redundant and can be changed to `(p.StartDate <= startDateUnix && endDateUnix <= p.EndDate)`. Do you agree?

Comment: @Rick sorry if I wasn't clear, I was saying part of the third line  -- not the first -- is redundant (so yes, I agree).

Comment: My bad - didn't read it properly lol!